# Objective-C initializers used by Swift (or not)

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, uikit, cgrectmake

In an app that was originally created in Objective-C but now with a lot of Swift code, initializing a `CGRect`, for example, using `CGRectMake` compiles just fine on a developer's Mac using Xcode, but produces an error `'CGRectMake' has been explicitly marked unavailable here` on the build server.

If I Command-Click on the function, I'm directed to the Objective_C header, where, given that message, I should see something like `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE`, but I don't. What would cause this different behavior on dev computers and the build server? More specifically, what can we do on the dev computer to generate the same errors the build server is generating?

We're using Xcode 14 with Swift 5.

Comment: I just checked, and the build server uses Xcode13. Maybe that's the difference.

Comment: Are you saying that you are using `CGRectMake` in Swift code? `CGRectMake` should only be used in Objective-C code, not Swift code. Use `CGRect(x:y:width:height:)` in Swift.

Comment: Yes, I know that. It was not I, but another dev who was using it, not that it matters. Yes, it's Swift code. The point is, using the Obj-C initializer does NOT produce an error except on the build server. Was it excluded in Xcode13 but not excluded in Xcode14 for some reason? What other explanation could there be? Why are we not getting that error message in Xcode14?

Comment: Something must have changed. I just realized that `CGRectMake` is listed in the Swift documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455245-cgrectmake) and I can use it in a Swift project with Xcode 14. I would have sworn it didn't exist in earlier versions of Swift. Sounds like you need to update your build server with Xcode 14.

Comment: Yeah, for other reasons. It's on the to-do list.

Comment: Even if calling `CGRectMake` from Swift is permitted, it'd seem better and more modern to use the Swift `CGRect()` initializer. `CGRectMake` only exists because structs in C and Obj-C don't have intializers; in Swift, they do, so it makes sense to use the one provided.

Comment: Agreed - so how can we get warnings to that effect? Possible?